# python3 utf-8 string save to utf-8?

Tags: python

I don't know the title that suits my situation.

```
data=[]

for title in titles:
     real_title = ''.join(str(title.text).split())
     print(real_title)
     data.append(real_title)

with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'result.json'), 'w+') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

when python ~~.py, result is very well.  print(real_title) show

```
이스케이프룸
```

but when I open json_file:

```
"\uc774\uc2a4\ucf00\uc774\ud504\ub8f8"
```

What's the problem? Why utf-8 letter is  literally saved to utf-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing are the Unicode escape codes; for example, `"\uc774"` is the character `이` with Unicode code point C774 16-bit hex.  This escape will occur by default for any character not in the ASCII range, 0 thru 127 decimal.

You can set the `ensure_ascii` parameter to `False`:

> If `ensure_ascii` is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to
>   have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If `ensure_ascii` is
>   false, these characters will be output as-is.

Example:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {"key": "이스케이프룸"}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"key": "\\uc774\\uc2a4\\ucf00\\uc774\\ud504\\ub8f8"}'
>>> json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
'{"key": "이스케이프룸"}'
```

Comment: Wow you are genius... Thank you.  `json.dump(data, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)` solve my problem!